# How to detect 'enter' character?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes, people send messages from their computer, but how can I find out where the line break was added in their text?

For example, in this text below:

```
ABC<br>
123
```

there is an *carriage return* between `C` and `1`

How can I detect this in JavaScript?

Comment: You say `carriage return between C and 1` but there's a `<br>` - are you looking to detect `<br>\n` or did you just mean `<br>`, not a literal newline character

Answer (score 1):

You can write listener for keydown event. Than you will recognize clicked button by keyCode property (ENTER = 13) of event object (event listener parameter).

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            function onKeyPress(event) {
                    switch (event.keyCode) {
                    case 13:
                        alert("You have clicked ENTER");
                        break;
                    default:
                }
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyPress, false);
            }
        //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks are encoded in JavaScript as `\n` which represents the unicode character `U+0010`.  A carriage return (`U+0013`) is `\r`.  Your string could be coded in JavaScript as:

```
"ABC\n123";
```

Or:

```
"ABC\r\n123";
```

You can also reference any character by codepoint using, eg, `\x10` or `\u0010`.

This article is a good read: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)